# Filter Div, BeautifulSoup, With Empty Return

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Running my algorithm below I seek to filter a `div`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for link in soup.select('div > a[href*="/tarefa"]'):
    ref=link.get('href')
    rt = ('https://brainly.com.br'+str(ref))
    p.append(rt)
print(p)
```

`Div` Below:

```
<div class="sg-content-box__content"><a href="/tarefa/2254726">
```

adjust:

```
<div class="sg-content-box"><a href="/tarefa/21670613">
```

But in doing this the Return is empty.**What could be the mistake in this part?**

Expected Exit: Examples.

```
/tarefa/2254726 

/tarefa/21670613
```

How do I need to check it out? Sometimes the page would end up changing the content where href is a high amount of data, needed something like 'div> a [href * = "/ task"]' so you could search for it. keyword 'task' and not the creation of a variable already containing the content.

Complete Algorithm:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


browser =webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:/path/geckodriver.exe')
browser.get('https://brainly.com.br/app/ask?entry=hero&q=jhyhv+vjh')

html = browser.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
p=[]
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for link in soup.select('div > a[href*=""]'):
    ref=link.get('href')
    rt = ('https://brainly.com.br'+str(ref))
    p.append(rt)
print(p)
```

Comment: check my answer and let me know if it works

Comment: Your code looks fine.Possible data rendered by java-scripts so you are getting empty results.Can you share your url if this public.

Comment: Eu que Estou Usando Selenium Pra Isso vou por Codigo Completo.

Comment: You could use selenium or you can check if there is an api for that.

Comment: I updated my problem and only code to filter with BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly happens that browser is taking more time load the data.Hence you are getting sometimes empty result.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for element `visibility_of_all_elements_located`()

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


browser =webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:/path/geckodriver.exe')
browser.get('https://brainly.com.br/app/ask?entry=hero&q=jhyhv+vjh')
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a[href*="/tarefa"]')))
html=browser.page_source
#html = browser.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
p=[]
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for link in soup.select('div.sg-actions-list__hole > a[href*="/tarefa"]'):
    ref=link.get('href')
    rt = ('https://brainly.com.br'+str(ref))
    p.append(rt)
print(p)
```

**Output**:

```
['https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/2254726', 'https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/21670613', 'https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/10188641', 'https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/22664332', 'https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/24152913', 'https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/11344228', 'https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/10888823', 'https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/23525186', 'https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/16838028', 'https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/24494056']
```

Comment: My Error Was selecting the correct div or the wrong wait time?.

Comment: I guess your search key was right but when you use selenium it needs some time to load the elements therefore Empty results come.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

test_html = '''
         <div class="sg-content-box__content"><a href="/tarefa/2254726"> 
         <div class="sg-content-box"><a href="/tarefa/21670613">
         '''

soup = BeautifulSoup(test_html, 'lxml')
p=[]
for link in soup.find_all('div'):
    ref=link.a.get('href')
    rt = ('https://brainly.com.br'+str(ref))
    p.append(rt)
print(p)
```

Comment: This would not fit because I have to filter other / task and not specifying that div so I didn't specify it, and I'm using the 'div> a [href * = "/ tarefa"]

Comment: post the sample html if possible

Comment: These are only 2 Divs, If You Have Any Way to Search by Keyword.

Comment: what  output you want just share.

Comment: I need the Href content:

Comment: check the my edited answer and accept the answer if it solved the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205464/discussion-between-soares-and-vikas-sharma).